# Integral $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \int_{\Lambda/s}^\Lambda \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{i}{y^2-x^2+i\epsilon} dydx = \pi\log s$

Tags: definite-integrals

I am stucked with the following integral
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \int_{\Lambda/s}^\Lambda \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{i}{y^2-x^2+i\epsilon} dydx = \pi\log s.$$
Here $s,\Lambda$ are positive constants. This integral is motivated from physics.
How can I evaluate this integral?

Comment: Is it x or y which is in [Λ/s,Λ] ? Besides, it is a little strange that Λ disappears in the limit...

Comment: @Jean Marie Of course it is $x$. I think the logarithm makes $\Lambda$ disappear, i.e. $\log\Lambda - \log (\Lambda/s) = \log s$.

Comment: Maybe by using "distributional" (=in the sense of the theory of distributions) equation (formula (110) in http://www.nbi.dk/~polesen/borel/node12.html) : $1/(y^2-x^2 +i \varepsilon)=PV (1/(y^2-x^2))-i \pi \delta(y^2-x^2)$ ?

Comment: I was forgetting to say that $1/(x+i\varepsilon)$ (think to $\epsilon$ as an "infinitesimal" although it should be considered as a symbolic expression) is a "full fledge" distribution that is met in particular in physics. See as well https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56482.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider first
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{i}{y^2-x^2+i\epsilon} dy$$
for fixed $x$. We will use the identity
$$\frac{1}{f+i\epsilon}=\mathrm{PV}\frac{1}{f}-i\pi\delta(f)\,,$$
where PV denotes the principal value.
Noting that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \mathrm{PV}\frac{1}{y^2-x^2}dy=
\frac{1}{2x}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  \mathrm{PV}\left(\frac{1}{y-x}-\frac{1}{y+x}\right)dy=0
$$
and
$$
\delta(y^2-x^2)dy=\frac{1}{2x}\left(
\delta(y-x)+\delta(y+x)
\right)dy\,,
$$
we then have
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{i}{y^2-x^2+i\epsilon} dy=\frac{\pi}{x}\,.$$
The integral over $x$ then yields
$$\pi\int_{\Lambda/s}^{\Lambda}\frac{dx}{x} = \pi\log s\,.
$$

Comment: I don't get how you get $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{i}{y^2-x^2+i\epsilon} dy=\frac{\pi}{x}\,.$ but this looks a lot easier as I suspected

Comment: @DanielD. I added a couple intermediate steps :)

Comment: Thanks I think I got it now, +1

Answer (score 2):

Write

$$ \frac{i}{y^2 - x^2 + i\epsilon} = \frac{i}{2\sqrt{x^2 - i\epsilon}} \left( \frac{1}{y - \sqrt{x^2 - i\epsilon}} - \frac{1}{y + \sqrt{x^2 - i\epsilon}} \right), $$

where $\sqrt{\,\cdot\,}$ is the principal square root. Also, note that for $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $ b \neq 0$,

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y - (a+ib)}
\stackrel{(y \mapsto y+a)}= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y - ib}
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{y+ib}{y^2 + b^2} \, \mathrm{d}y
= i \pi \operatorname{sign}(b). $$

Together with the fact that $\operatorname{Im}(\sqrt{x^2-i\epsilon}) < 0$, this gives

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{i}{y^2 - x^2 + i\epsilon} \, \mathrm{d}y
= \frac{i}{2\sqrt{x^2 - i\epsilon}} \bigl((-\pi i) - (\pi i)\bigr) = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{x^2 - i\epsilon}}. $$

Finally, by the Dominated Convergence Theorem,

$$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{\Lambda/s}^{\Lambda} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{i}{y^2 - x^2 + i\epsilon} \, \mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x
= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{\Lambda/s}^{\Lambda} \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{x^2 - i\epsilon}} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{\Lambda/s}^{\Lambda} \frac{\pi}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \pi \log s. $$

Answer (score 1):

First lets caculate our integral as a contour integral

$\oint_C \frac{-i}{z^2-x^2+i\epsilon}dz\\
=\oint_C \frac{-i}{(y+iu)^2-x^2+i\epsilon}d(y+iu)\\
=\int_{\{y\in(R,-R),u=0\}}\frac{-i}{(y+iu)^2-x^2+i\epsilon}d(y+iu)+\int_{\{y+íu=Re^{i\theta},\theta\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)\}} \frac{-i}{(y+iu)^2-x^2+i\epsilon}d(y+iu)\\
=\int_R^{-R}\frac{-i}{y^2-x^2+i\epsilon}d(y)+\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{-i}{R^2e^{i2\phi}-x^2+i\epsilon}d(Re^{i\phi})\\
=\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}\frac{-i}{y^2-x^2+i\epsilon}dy+0\\
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{i}{y^2-x^2+i\epsilon}dy
$

Now lets use the residue theorem

$\oint_C \frac{-i}{z^2-x^2+i\epsilon}dz\\
=2\pi i \sum_{z^*\in C}\operatorname{Res}(\frac{-i}{z^2-x^2+i\epsilon},z^*)\\
=2\pi i\operatorname{Res}(\frac{-i}{z^2-x^2+i\epsilon},\sqrt{x^2-i\epsilon})\\
=2\pi i\lim(z-(\sqrt{x^2-i\epsilon}))\frac{-i}{z^2-x^2+i\epsilon}\\
=2\pi i\lim(z-(\sqrt{x^2-i\epsilon}))\frac{.i}{(z-\sqrt{x^2-i\epsilon})(z+\sqrt{x^2-i\epsilon})}\\
=2\pi i\lim_{z\to\sqrt{x^2-i\epsilon}}\frac{-i}{z+\sqrt{x^2-i\epsilon}}\\
=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{x^2-i\epsilon}}\\
$

Finally lets caculate the entire integral

$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\Lambda/s}^\Lambda\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{i}{y^2-x^2+i\epsilon}dydx\\
=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\Lambda/s}^\Lambda\oint_C \frac{-i}{z^2-x^2+i\epsilon}dzdx\\
=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\Lambda/s}^\Lambda\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{x^2-i\epsilon}}dx\\
=\pi\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\ln(\sqrt{x^2-i\epsilon}+x)|_{\Lambda/s}^\Lambda\\
=\pi\ln(2x)|_{\Lambda/s}^\Lambda\\
=\pi\ln(s)\\
$

$\therefore\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\Lambda/s}^\Lambda \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{i}{y^2-x^2+i\epsilon} dydx=\pi\ln(s)$

For the last integral I just asked [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%281%2Fsqrt%28x%5E2-a%29%29)

Also I think that using $1/(y^2-x^2 +i \varepsilon)=PV (1/(y^2-x^2))-i \pi \delta(y^2-x^2)$ as mention in the comment it should be easier but I'm not sure how to apply it.